# SQL Insert Multiple Rows with Select and Static Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, insert

I'm new to stored procedures (I have been doing them for all of 4 hours now), so my question might be very simple, but I am having zero luck googling for the solution.

I have a temp table called `#InvoicesTemp` and an existing table called `Notification`, and I need to create a new row in `Notification` for each row in `#InvoicesTemp`. Most of the data in inserted rows will be the same so I am trying to hard code those values. My insert looks like this:

```
Insert into Notification(InvoiceId, Message, CreatedDate, Boolean1, Boolean2, Boolean3)
   select 
      tmp.InvoiceId, 'Invoice ' + tmp.InvoiceString + @message, GETDATE(), 1, 0, 0    
   from 
      #InvoicesTemp tmp
```

My problem is that although my temp table has multiple rows, the call is only adding one row to the Notification table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your sql.  The most likely explanation is that you're wrong about the number of rows in your temp table.   Try commenting out the insert and see what just the select query produces.

Comment: Oh wow, that wasn't the problem, but you did make me realize that I might have my select wrong when verifying my results in my Notification table (a where clause was still there from earlier in the day). Such a stupid thing, but my lack of confidence in my sql knowledge led me to believe something else was wrong. Thanks!